# NullPointerException in receiver

Tags: android

I have a user getting a `NullPointerException` in my one BroadcastReceiver the stacktrace is below

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver ecm2.android.NetworkReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2821)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3200(ActivityThread.java:125)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2083)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:75)
at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:2678)
at ecm2.android.NetworkReceiver.onReceive(NetworkReceiver.java:39)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2810)
```

now obviously something is null but then line that it points to is a pending intent so its hard to tell what is null

here is the code

```
Context c = MainActivity.getContext();
mAlarmSender2 = PendingIntent.getService(c, 0, new Intent(c, EMGNoteService.class), 0); //line that throws the error
```

basically I am trying to cancel an `AlarmManager` that was set so the only thing it could be is the context is null correct?

I am just not sure because the stacktrace is saying something about the `ComponentName` and `Intent` so I didnt know if there was something wrong with the intent

Comment: I think the problem is your context. Since it is also used to initialize the intent, there would be an error there.

Comment: @iNan all the onReceive does in this instance is cancel any alarms, nothing significant enough that would relate to this issue, the two lines are the only relative code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem was indeed my context so I changed that and it fixed it